# DBT/ Oracle error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbt

When working on DBT (DATA BUILD TOOL) with oracle . I am creating a snapshot table of customers phone number I am getting the ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables.

I have checked the uniqueness of my unique key key and no duplicates

NB: the snapshot was running fine for 10 days and failed today

Answer (score 0):

> Cause:

The issue is because dbt generated two different records (two different unique key) with the same changing dimension id (dbt_scd_id) to be updated. So dbt try to update one record twice.

> Solution:

In the target > run > snapshots > <snapshot_name> add the code below after the using

```
select * from your_table 
where dbt_scd_id not in(
        select dbt_scd_id
        from your_table 
        group by dbt_scd_id
        having count(*) > 1)
```

This will select only records with no duplicates.

NB: your_table = the dbt generated table